# Error in Flash addition

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, floating-point

Make a **new AS3 Document** in Flash, **paste** in the following code and **run it:**

```
var a:Number=0;
trace(a)  //  0
a+=0.3;
trace(a)  //  0.3
a+=0.3;
trace(a)  //  0.6
a+=0.3;

trace(a)  //  0.8999999999999999
a+=0.3;
trace(a)  //  1.2
a+=0.3;
trace(a)  //  1.5
a+=0.3;
trace(a)  //  1.8
a+=0.3;
trace(a)  //  2.1
a+=0.3;
          //  ^ This is the output. Notice the inaccuracy starting from 0.9 / 0.89
```

**Why the error?** I'm just doing an ordinary hi resolution addition.

Any **workarounds?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standard floating point problem. Binary floating point numbers do not represent the full range of decimal numbers with perfect accuracy, you need to do something along the lines of

```
trace (round (a, 1))
```

or, better yet, turn it into a string and strip off everything past the first fractional digit (since the result of round may also not be easily representable in binary).

although I don't know ActionScript. Still it's a very well known issue and not limited to AS3.

See for example [Why do I see a double variable initialized to some value like 21.4 as 21.399999618530273?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177506/why-do-i-see-a-double-variable-initialized-to-some-value-like-214-as-2139999961) or [Strange floating-point behaviour in a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327544/strange-floating-point-behaviour-in-a-java-program) or [What is a simple example of floating point/rounding error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-pointrounding-error).

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to use a scaled integer type.  For this example, you could increment by 3, and then divide by 10 just before output.  That avoids all the rounding errors inherent in floating point arithmetic.