# C - Simple division (1/n) results in strange answers

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate a simple approximation to an integral by dividing it up into a step function, easy stuff. The problem starts when I simply try to do a division. Here is my code:

```
double integrand(int a, double div, int n) {
    int i;
    double sum, val;

    val = 1.0/div;

    for(i = 0; i < div; i++) {
        sum = sum + (pow(i*val, n)/(i*val + a)) * val;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here div is actually an integer, I tried bringing it into the integrand function originally as an integer and typecasting it to a double inside the function, with the same result. When I debug the code, div can be say, 100, yet val will return something ludicrous like -7.2008557565654656e+304. As far as I'm aware the rest of the code is correct, but I just cannot figure this out, what's going on?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange result of division in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985601/strange-result-of-division-in-c)

Comment: I've already considered the possibility of floating point inaccuracies, but I didn't expect an arbitrarily enormous result for 1 /100..

Comment: This `val = 1.0/div;` gives you something like `-7.2008557565654656e+304` for `val`?

Comment: Did you try to remove that loop that makes use of "unitialised sum" and just print the value of val=1.0/div? it should just be 0.01

Comment: @DanielA.White: This does not seem to be a duplicate of what you linked.

Comment: Log `div` prior to taking the reciprocal (1/x), perhaps is not receiving what you think it would. Did you ran this in a debugger and inspected the values?

Comment: No, `div` is not actually an integer. It will be promoted to a `double` at the call site before entering your function - you may actually be calling the function with an integer, but the compiler will make sure that by the time that `div` exists in your function, it will have been converted.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized `sum`:

```
double sum = 0, val;
```

Right now, you're using it in your calculation with an uninitialized value, and hence getting some garbage results.

Comment: Feel like an idiot now, it seems not giving sum an initial value was screwing with val, it assigns just fine now. Apologies for a crap question.

Comment: @user3014043: No worries, we've all been there, and more often than we'd like to admit ;).

Answer (score 1):

First initialize `sum` and then use it. Otherwise it will invoke **undefined behavior**.