# Why does JSP/JSTL division by 1000 sometimes give remainder?

Tags: java, jsp, floating-point, jstl

When dividing by 1000 I sometime run across a bug that doesn't do the division "correctly".  For example, when dividing 90.55 by 1000 instead of getting .09055 I get .090549999999.

```
<c:out value="${bean.paPrice / 1000}" />
```

Why is this happening?  Is this a result of floating point math?  A google search seemed to indicate that this may be a culprit, but I have found no concrete answer.

To fix this I can round the answer to 5 digits, but it seems like this is just a patch to a deeper problem.

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" maxFractionDigits="5" value="${bean.paPrice / 1000}" />
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327544/strange-floating-point-behaviour-in-a-java-program

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-doubles-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem, it's just a natural result of the binary representation of floating point. Round your values and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Why do computers suck at math?

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001266.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a common [floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) issue.