# Multiplying doubles in java?

Tags: java, android, math, double, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply the same double (square it) but the number comes out wrong. When i display the double by itself the number is correct but when i multiply it by itself it comes up with the wrong number. I already tried using the math.pow function and got the same result.

```
    Double height=Double.parseDouble(myPrefs.getString("Heightent",""))*.0254;
    Double bmi = (height*height);
    dbmi.setText(bmi.toString());
```

Height is entered in a different activity in inches. When i display height in a text box it comes out to be the right number. For example, Heightent entered is 74 and 1.8796 is displayed when i put height in a textview. Butwhen I use the code above the number 16 is displayed in TextView dbmi. Any help?

Comment: can try  hTemp = height.doubleValue();  Double bmi = (hTemp *hTemp );

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you are using the wrapper classes?

Comment: using what you said 'height = 74 * .0254' and now squaring the height my output is 3.532?

Comment: I'm not able toString with a primitive type. Is there an easier way?

Comment: It should be 3.532 but somehow it comes out as 16 in the program.

Comment: By putting Double.parseDouble(myPrefs.getString("Heightent",""))*.0254 in parentheses it fixed the problem.

Comment: You can just do ""+someDoubleValue with the primitive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this great post by Stephen C.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385202/1214163

It should provide everything you need. He suggests that if you need to work with big numbers that you use the `BigDecimal` class

Comment: BigDecimal is a great class. I feel its harder to do multiplication with it though but that might come from my inexperience with the class. By putting Double.parseDouble(myPrefs.getString("Heightent",""))*.0254 in parentheses it fixed the problem. I'm going to accept your answer though because BigDecimal is a great class to use and be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both

```
    Double height=Double.parseDouble("74")*.0254;
    Double bmi = (height*height);
    System.out.println("first " + bmi);


      height=Double.parseDouble("74");
      double temp = height.doubleValue()*.0254;
      bmi = (temp*temp);
      System.out.println("Second " + bmi);
```

and on *Calc*

and got same every where.....
[image]