# Android. 4.1 - 4 = 0.09999999999999964. Why?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android number format is wrong somehow, instead of 3.5 I get 3.499999999, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065397/android-number-format-is-wrong-somehow-instead-of-3-5-i-get-3-499999999-why)

Does any one know why Android platform gives such strange result?

**4.1 - 4  = 0.09999999999999964**

It's only 4 that gives such strange rounding.

Actually I need to get mantissa from 4.1 so I need 0.1 as result but not 0.09999999999999964.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should research floating point operations, and number formatting.

Comment: You should use `BigDecimal` for this kind of operations, if you want the exact calculation.

Comment: Guys, if you're giving minus. Please explain to Anton. @Anton, if you're working with money it's better to use another datatype from Double and Float

Comment: also, it is NOT true that ONLY 4 gives this kind of result. I think that `0.09999999999999964` is the closest aproximation of 0.1 for floats

Comment: To do fixed-precision math in many languages you should multiply by a power of ten, then after the calculation, divide by the same power of ten. The quotient is the integer portion of the result. The remainder is the fractional portion. If you want variable precision in the calculation, but fixed precision for the output, use floating point types and NumberFormat to print it.

Comment: `BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("4.1").subtract(new BigDecimal("4")); double d = c.doubleValue();` This would give you **0.1**

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of rounding. You can take a look at the [BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class which should do what you need.

Comment: For example: `BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal("4.1").subtract(new BigDecimal("4")); double d = c.doubleValue();`

Comment: Thanks, but nope, it does not do the trick. The result of such construction is also 0.09999999999999964.