# exponential growth in java, return type array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, exponential

Im working on a CS assignment and Im having a little trouble understanding how to output an array of doubles that represent the amt of money in a bank account at increments of time given a user specified growth rate.  I have a main method that asks the user for initialAmount of $, a growthRate and the number of time intervals (denoted iA, gR and nP for inital Amount, growth Rate and number of Periods).  this method then calls another method which is of return type double[].  My issue is with the code inside my for-loop, it compiles fine but outputs gibberish.  heres the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Benford {
    public static double[] generateBenfordNumbers (double iA, double gR, int nP) {  
        double[] bankStatement = new double[nP];

        for (int i = 0; i<nP; i++) { 
            bankStatement[i] = (iA*(Math.pow((1+(gR)), (i++))));
        }

        return bankStatement;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        double iA;
        double gR;
        int nP;

        System.out.print("What is the initial amount of money that you are starting with? : ");
        iA = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("What is the amount of growth per time period? : ");
        gR = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("How many time periods would you like to use? : ");
        nP = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println();

        generateBenfordNumbers(iA, gR, nP);
        System.out.print(generateBenfordNumbers(iA, gR, nP));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by gibberish output? What exactly disturbs you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line

```
bankStatement[i] = (iA*(Math.pow((1+(gR)), (i++))));
```

`i++` increments `i` a second time. You probably want:

```
bankStatement[i] = (iA*(Math.pow((1+(gR)), i + 1)));
```

or, if we clean it up,

```
bankStatement[i] = iA * Math.pow(1 + gR, i + 1);
```

`i + 1` returns a value 1 greater than that of `i`, but does not actually increment the variable itself.

---

Also, do you really have to use `Math.pow` each time? Can't you just manually set the first element of your array to `iA` and subsequently use `bankStatement[i-1]` to compute `bankStatement[i]`? Doing something like this will probably improve your program.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that did the trick, only thing is when I use a simple example like:  iA=100, gR=.10, nP= whatever, I get [100.0, 110.00000000001, 121.00000000001 etc, just trying to figure out why im getting these tiny fractions at the end.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user1730099 Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327544/strange-floating-point-behaviour-in-a-java-program).

Answer (score 1):

i is incremented twice : at loop level and into the body

Answer (score 1):

The gibberish output looks like this:

```
[D@1b67f74
```

which is s double array text representation. You could use:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(generateBenfordNumbers(iA, gR, nP)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be incrementing i inside your call to Math.pow. This is because you already increment it in your for loop. The result is that elements of your array are getting skipped and not set. This is probably where the gibberish-ness is coming from.

You probably want to change:

```
bankStatement[i] = (iA*(Math.pow((1+(gR)), (i++))));
```

To:

```
bankStatement[i] = iA*Math.pow(1+gR, i);
```

Also, as an aside, you generally shouldn't use so many parenthesis because it makes it hard to read. If you're not sure what the order of operations is, [look it up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

What the others said, you're incrementing i twice so I'm not going to repeat that.  I just want to add that brackets are good to organize formulas and to ensure correct execution order of calculations, but if you overuse them, they can obfuscate the intention of your program and they may make the problem you're looking for harder to spot. Compare

```
bankStatement[i] = iA * Math.pow(1.0 + gR, i+1);
```

with

```
bankStatement[i] = (iA*(Math.pow((1+(gR)), (i))));
```

See what I mean?

EDIT - following ARS very valid remark about the initial value of i, I changed the cleaned up statement.