# Weird double printing in array

Tags: java, arrays, printing, double

I'm writing a program that prints an array containing the sum of the values of two arrays passed as parameters. It all works fine with the exception of the last double value. I want the last value to print as 3.1. Instead it's printing the following:

[5.9, 11.7, 2.4, 3.0999999999999996]

Not sure how to format to print otherwise as I'm not allowed to use a String to solve it. I'm not having that problem with the other values. Here's my code and thanks for the help!

```
    import java.util.*;

class Sum
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        double [] a1 = {4.5, 2.8, 3.4, 0.8};
        double [] a2 = {1.4, 8.9, -1.0, 2.3};

        arraySum (a1, a2);

        System.out.println (Arrays.toString (arraySum (a1, a2)));   
    }

    public static double [] arraySum (double [] x, double [] y)
    {
        int length = 0;
        double [] sum = new double [x.length];
        length = x.length;

            for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
            {
                sum[i] = x[i] + y[i];
            }

        return sum;

    }
}
```

Comment: this is because of binary floating point, which is one of the most basic things that programmers must know

Answer (score 3):

You want to use deciaml format

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.#");
String outputString=df.format(sum);
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a String to format the problem, though...

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the IEEE floating point model. It can't represent exactly `3.1`. To print it like you want, you will have to do it manually, instead of using `Arrays.toString`. Loop over the doubles and format them:

```
public static String toString(double[] x, DecimalFormat format)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i)
    {
        sb.append(format.format(x[i]));
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And then call like:

```
toString(sum, new DecimalFormat("#.#"));
```

---

To do the trick using only doubles, you might try to apply this, but this is dirty and not guaranteed to work:

```
double x = ...;
x = 0.001 * Math.round(x * 1000.0);
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Problem is I can't use a String to solve it...

Comment: Good answer, only criticism is that String.format will have to parse the format string for every element in the array. Perhaps a DecimalFormat will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The number is still correct if you round to a reasonable amount of sigfigs which is what DecimalFormat and String.format will do for you under the covers. As @neminem said this is caused by the same issue as [Strange floating-point behaviour in a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327544/strange-floating-point-behaviour-in-a-java-program). If it really is a big deal to you that the actual number represented be accurate to sigfigs > ~8 than consider using BigDecimal as you will never lose any precision.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use `System.out.printf()` to solve the problem, then your only choice is to use `BigDecimal` objects to hold the values.  There is *no way* that you will ever get a `3.1` result out of a `double` without one of those two methods (or `DecimalFormat`).

You say that you "can't use String to solve it", but I don't think that doing...

```
for (double d : arraySum (a1, a2)) {
    System.out.printf("%.1f\n", d);
}
```

qualifies as "using a String to solve it".  Seems perfectly legitimate to me.